# Shell script to display the first 12 command-line arguments of the "ls" command

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I'm trying to create a script that echoes the first 12 arguments of ls command. We are supposed to do it using the "shift" syntax build into the shell, but im having a hard time understanding how the shift command works (Yes, I looked it up, tried it, and cant figure it out). If anyone can point me in the right direction of how to use the shift command to accomplish this goal, it would be much appreciated. I posted what ive tried so far belore (Fair warning, it endlessly loops, if you try to run it yourself)

```
    #!/bin/sh

args=a A b c C d e E f F g h H
while [ $# -lt 12 ]
do
    echo ls -$#
    count=`expr $# + 1`
    shift
done
```

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html#EX19

Comment: tldp is not a great place for learning about shell.  I have heard that it has many inaccuracies and hence it is best to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -- a A b c C d e E f F g h H # set argument list to have 12 values
i=0
while ((i < 12)); do             # loop until we scan 12 arguments
  ls -- "$1"                     # do ls with the current argument
  ((i++))
  shift                          # shift left so that $2 becomes $1 and so on
  if (($# == 0)); then break; fi # break if no more arguments
done
```

Answer (score 0):

A solid way to handle shift for all POSIX shells is to use `$#` within a while loop using the arithmetic comparison `(( $# ))`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

while (( $# )); do
    echo "$1"
    shift
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sh shiftargs.sh a A b c C d e E f F g h H
a
A
b
c
C
d
e
E
f
F
g
h
H
```

Answer (score 0):

`shift` removes the first element of the arguments array. If your script is run with 12 or more arguments, the loop is skipped. If run with less than 12 arguments (as in your example), each argument will be printed, then shifted off. The while loop conditional is infinitely true because the array length will always be less than 12.

```
#!/bin/sh

count=0
while [ $# -gt 0 ] && [ $count -lt 12 ]
do
    echo ls -$1
    shift
    (( count++ ))
done
```

See [shift reference](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html).